# Code not display the board, only background

Tags: javascript, arrays

My board isn't being displayed, only the background which I set. This is for a school project draft, and the teacher kind of hates me. if you solve it could you explain it in simple language.

Hopefully you can understand this code, as it is the teacher's that used to be for mindsweeper, but is reused for a different game.

```
//global variables
let gameBoard           //holds information about the state of the board      
let size = 15          //horz and vert size of the board
 
//runs once at the start
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight)
    gameBoard = createBoard(size)
}


function draw() {
 
    background(220)
    translate(windowWidth/2 - size/2*30, windowHeight/2 - size/2*30)

    for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {
            gameBoard[x][y].draw()
        }
    }

}

function createBoard(size) {

    let board = []

    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        let row = []
        for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            let square = new SQUARE(i, j)
            row.push(square)
        }
        board.push(row)
    }


  

}
```

```
class SQUARE {

    constructor(column,row){
                   this.x = column
                   this.y = row
    }

    draw(){
    rect(this.x*30, this.y*30, 30, 30)
    }
}
```

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="p5.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="Square.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>

</head>


<body>



</body>




</html>
```

I tried and expected A board to appear, it just displayed a blank background.

Answer (score 0):

Your finction `CreateBoard` doesn't return anything, even though you try to get the array from it in `gameBoard = createBoard(size)`.
Try to add `return board;` in the end of function `CreateBoard`

```
function createBoard(size) {

    let board = []

    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        let row = []
        for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            let square = new SQUARE(i, j)
            row.push(square)
        }
        board.push(row)
    }
    return board;
}
```